# Plot confidence interval of a duration series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I measured the duration of 6000 requests.

I got now an Array of 6000 elements. Each element represents the duration of a connection request in milliseconds.
`[3,2,2,3,4,2,2,4,2,3,3,4,2,4,4,3,3,3,4,3,2,3,5,5,2,4,4,2,2,2,3,5,3,2,2,3,3,3,5,4........]`

I want to plot the confidence interval in Python and in a clearly arranged manner.

Do you have any Idea how I should plot them?

Comment: What do you mean by plotting the confidence interval? CI is just one value (well, two). Since you have one value for each time point, you can get one CI for the whole series

Comment: Try: https://dreisbach.us/articles/p-values-and-confidence-intervals/

Comment: I have on the y-axis unit called operation and on the x-axis the time in ms. I calculated from the array the average duration which is  2.6585 milliseconds. The CI lies between 2.635 ms and 2.682 ms. I want to plot the average value and values where the  CI lies. Perfect if I can somehow add also Outliers to the plot

Comment: @back2stackoverflow I don't think the CI over the whole time series is meaningful. What you usually do is calculate the CI for each time point (assuming you have many 6000-element arrays). But plotting a time series surrounded by the CI of the average seems peculiar to me.
I suggest reconsidering what you are after.

Comment: I have only one 6000-element array for one operation. The operation is the request itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood this code should answer your question

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
from statistics import NormalDist

X = np.random.sample(100)
data = ((X - min(X)) / (max(X) - min(X))) * 3 + 3
confidence_interval = 0.95

def getCI(data, ci):
    normalDist = NormalDist.from_samples(data)
    z = NormalDist().inv_cdf((1 + ci) / 2.)
    p = normalDist.stdev * z / ((len(data) - 1) ** .5)
    return normalDist.mean, normalDist.mean - p, normalDist.mean + p

avg, lower, upper = getCI(data, confidence_interval)
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
sns.histplot(data, bins = 10)
plt.axvspan(lower, upper, facecolor='r', alpha=0.2)
plt.axvline(avg, color = 'b', label = 'Average')
plt.ylabel("Operations")
plt.xlabel("Connection Request Duration (ms)")

plt.show()
```

[image]

For boxplot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
from statistics import NormalDist

X = np.random.sample(100)
data = ((X - min(X)) / (max(X) - min(X))) * 3 + 3
confidence_interval = 0.95

def getCI(data, ci):
    normalDist = NormalDist.from_samples(data)
    z = NormalDist().inv_cdf((1 + ci) / 2.)
    p = normalDist.stdev * z / ((len(data) - 1) ** .5)
    return normalDist.mean, normalDist.mean - p, normalDist.mean + p

avg, lower, upper = getCI(data, confidence_interval)
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
sns.boxplot(data = data, orient = "h")
plt.axvspan(lower, upper, facecolor='r', alpha=0.4)
plt.axvline(avg, color = 'b', label = 'Average')
plt.ylabel("Operations")
plt.xlabel("Connection Request Duration (ms)")
plt.yticks([0],["Server Retry Request Delay"])

plt.savefig("fig.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

For Multiple Plots:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
from statistics import NormalDist

X1, X2 = np.random.sample(100), np.random.sample(100)
data1, data2 = ((X1 - min(X1)) / (max(X1) - min(X1))) * 3 + 3, ((X2 - min(X2)) / (max(X2) - min(X2))) * 2 + 3
confidence_interval = 0.95

def getCI(data, ci):
    normalDist = NormalDist.from_samples(data)
    z = NormalDist().inv_cdf((1 + ci) / 2.)
    p = normalDist.stdev * z / ((len(data) - 1) ** .5)
    return normalDist.mean, normalDist.mean - p, normalDist.mean + p

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
avg1, lower1, upper1 = getCI(data1, confidence_interval)
avg2, lower2, upper2 = getCI(data2, confidence_interval)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212, sharex = ax1, sharey = ax1)

sns.boxplot(data = data1, orient = "h", ax = ax1)
ax1.axvspan(lower1, upper1, facecolor='r', alpha=0.4)
ax1.axvline(avg1, color = 'b', label = 'Average')

sns.boxplot(data = data2, orient = "h", ax = ax2)
ax2.axvspan(lower2, upper2, facecolor='r', alpha=0.4)
ax2.axvline(avg2, color = 'b', label = 'Average')
ax2.set_xlabel("Connection Request Duration (ms)")

plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax1.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax2.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
fig.text(0.08, 0.5, "Operations", va='center', rotation='vertical')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: can you change the axis like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6mOH.png ?

Comment: could you kindly elaborate which part you want to be changed ?
cause I think it's a similar axis
Did you mean to make the plot horizontal ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD7xz.png. Look i tried to plot the data in a boxplot but its not good illustration. The y-axis contains only one operation and ths x-axis the time in ms. I need just one operation on the y-axis

Comment: the notches in the boxplot are wrong and is  not showing the average but the median

Comment: Boxplots show median as a line and mean as a dot (it is optional).
The box ranges from 1st Quartile to 3rd Quartile.
Are you trying to shade confidence interval on a boxplot ?

Comment: perfect mate. That's the answer

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad you found it useful!

Comment: @salm Bonda do you know how to add a second boxplot like that under each other

Comment: Representing the same data or a new dataset ?

Comment: something like this but the boxplots like you did: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Pdzh.png

Comment: @salm Bonda do you have a solution. I am really stuck since i am newbie in python

Comment: What does the second boxplot indicate ? Some other data ?

Comment: I updated the answer, is that what you are trying to plot ?